# Is multi encryption a good way to wipe all traces of personal data before selling the phone?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, encryption, privacy, delete

I am going to sell my phone.

It's a Samsung Galaxy S4 i9505 from Germany running Android 5.0.1 "Lollipop". What I have done so far is to encrypt, reset, run camera until memory was full to override empty memory with random data and then reset again. But I think I have forgot to disable "fast encryption" which encrypts only the used memory (I have manually deleted some files before ). I am not sure if I have disabled it or not.

Is it a good idea to perform the encryption again (with "full encryption"), or is multiple encryption a bad idea in case of security?

Comment: Well I think another encryption on encryped data is not a security risk, because then an attacker could encrypt some encrypet data again and this makes no sense that then he could get the data easier. But it also does not make it more secure. I think I will encrypt the phone again without "fast encryption" enabled and then sell it. Then the original data is encrypted, overridden by random data, and then again encrypted. And the possibility that my phone will be hacked by an attacker is very low. PS: The external SD card will not be sold. It is in my new phone.